# How to apply multiple filters to the column

Tags: java, swing, filter, jide

I have a filter applied to my column, which is considering a single filter option. How can I apply multiple filters to the same column.

```
AbstractFilter filter;
WildcardFilter<Object> filter = new WildcardFilter<Object>(filterValue) {
                        @Override
                        @SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")
                        public boolean isValueFiltered(final Object result) {
                            boolean isValueFiltered = super.isValueFiltered(s);
                            isValueFiltered;
                        }
                    };
                       filter.setBeginWith(false);
                       filter.setEndWith(false);
                       filter = filter;
```

Comment: Are you referring to a [JIDE] [grid](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm)?

Comment: @Abra I am using com.jidesoft.filter.* . Thanks

Comment: don't they support chaining similar to core predicates?

Comment: @kleopatra I am currently learning about swing. Can you please elaborate or share a link. Thank you

Comment: see java.util.Predicate and compare the api of jidesoft Filter with it (don't know whether or not the latter has something similar, it's rather oldish afair - but you can implement something similar yourself, probably :)

Comment: I was able to make it work using AndFilter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to combine Multiple filters using AndFilter.